# Can memoization cause RESTART: Shell in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the python code below which doesn't use anything, but stock python libraries. The code runs fine is greatly speed-up by the menoization, but at some point the IDLE shell just restarts with message RESTART: Shell. No error / exception so the try catch is useless.

```
import sys
import time

def Display(result,start):
    print('Run time ' + str(time.time()-start) + '!')
    print('Answer ' + str(result) + '!')

class Memoire:
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.func = function
        self.memo = {}

    def __call__(self,arguments):
        arg = self.genarg(arguments)
        if (arg not in self.memo):
            self.memo[arg] = self.func(arguments)
        return self.memo[arg]

    def value(self,arguments):
        return self.memo[self.genarg(arguments)]

    def genarg(self,arguments):
        arg = ''
        for i in arguments:
            arg = arg + str(i)+','
        return arg
    def clear(self):
        self.memo = {}

@Memoire
def w(arg):
    # arg[0] = c = value
    # arg[1] = t = total
    if arg[0] == 1 or arg[1] == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        summ = 0
        for i in range(arg[1]//arg[0]+1):
            summ = summ + w([arg[0]-1,arg[1]-arg[0]*i])
        return summ



def main(n):
    sys.setrecursionlimit(2**16-1)
    start = time.time()
    i = 1
    k = w([i,i])
    
    try:
        while k%n != 0:
            i = i + 1
            k = w([i,i])
            print(i)
            if(i%100 == 0):
                print(i,k)
            

        Display(i,start)
    except:
        print('Hello world')
    print('Hello world')
    

main(10**6)
```

It happens when i reaches 1268, or 1269, or 1270 with preference to 1269. I tried running from the command line only diffrence is that on average it seems to make it to 1270 instead of 1269. Not sure if this could be an issue with the menoization and running out of memory, but I would assume I'd get an error if that was the case. Never had an issue that didn't give an error in Python before any idea on what I should check would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're likely blowing the stack. If you find the need to use `setrecursionlimit`, you probably shouldn't be using recursion at all.

Comment: If you are able to compute `summ = summ + w([arg[0]-1,arg[1]-arg[0]*i])` with iteration instead you likely will not run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, by blowing the stack do you mean hit the recursion limit? Only needs to go i deep in the recursion and adds i values to the menoization for every number it tries so when i get to 1270 it should have stored 807085 values.

Comment: I'll try and make it iteration based see if that works it just made so much more sense to me as a recursion.

Comment: FYI:  `functools.cache` is the built-in version of your `Memoire` class.  No need to re-invent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just tried it with my code above and improved it so it could go down to 1395 before it 'crashed' instead of 1270.

Comment: you say memoisation, but use recursion ?  might be worth watching this:  https://youtu.be/1podU0jN4aU

Comment: The @Memoire part is the menoization it stores the value of previous function calls in a dictionary and which is in the class. It's take same thing as what is shared in you video but there he explicitly makes the dictionary part of the function instead of using a class wrapper. Your video also uses recursion they simply doing the Fibonacci sequence instead.